# How to use gallery component with all images?

Tags: android, image, gallery

I want to show in a gallery component some images. I see a lot of guide and in all of them the images loaded was into drawable folder. But i want to add the images to gallery dynamically from code and not to specify it or put it on drawable folder. I want to display some image that i take with my app and convert to byte. After i want to reconvert to .jpeg and show on this gallery. Is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this to add image into gallery

```
  MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "your title","
  your description")
```

or use this if you want to insert then get the path from it

```
  String path=MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "your title","your description").toString();
```